# mysql like issue on partial match

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Im having a `mysql` query like this

```
SELECT group_name FROM t_groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%PCB%';
```

The results are

```
group_name
------------
PCB
Full size PCB
```

Another query,

```
SELECT group_name FROM t_groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%PCB-123%';

group_name
-----------
PCB-123
```

How can i use a query that will show all the three results ?,I mean i need to get all the results that starts or contains **PCB**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

as you have changed the context of your question so below is my updated answer

```
SELECT group_name FROM t_groups WHERE group_name RLIKE '[PCB]'
```

Comment: Thank you ! let me chk and will get back to you

Comment: This is matching all the records i needed as well as the records starting or containing P or C or B..anyway to limit it ?

Comment: now you have change the context of you question. anyways write `[PCB]`

Comment: Ya i changed your answer to
select group_name from t_groups where group_name RLIKE '[PCB]'

Comment: Your answer is working fine..but along with the results ..im getting the results that starts or contains with either P or C or B

Comment: thats you wanted, see the comments. Please be specific what u exactly want.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT group_name FROM test WHERE group_name LIKE '%PCB%'
```

this is working fine in mysql , check [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c885/4)

Answer (score 1):

I have executed your query

```
SELECT group_name FROM t_groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%PCB%';
```

Works fine for me . It returned 3 records

Can you explain what type of datatype you have used for group_name column