# Regular expression matching in mysql instead of like

Tags: mysql, sql-like

My previous question seems to be unclear.so im putting a new question with more clear data

[mysql like issue on partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907712/mysql-like-issue-on-partial-match)

The query

```
SELECT * FROM t_groups WHERE group_name LIKE '%pla%'
```

The results

[image]

MY question is when user search for something like 'plablablabla',How can i show all the results in the above image..i tried `LIKE` and `RLIKE` and im not good with regular expressions..any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you need the mysql `regexp` keyword. More info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_groups 
WHERE group_name REGEXP 'pla'
```

Comment: empty results when i searched `SELECT * 
FROM t_groups 
WHERE group_name REGEXP 'plablablaaa';`

Comment: because `plablablaaa` is not contained on the list above. so you want to search for `plablablaaa` but still display `Plain`? how is that possible.

Comment: Because Plain and plablabla both starts with 'pla'..anyway to do with regular expression ?